# How to configure Selenium Grid with Marathon driver (Java Driver) to execute tests of Java Swing Desktop Application?

Tags: swing, selenium-grid, marathontesting

I am not able to find any Selenium Grid configuration for Marathon driver
Below is code that i have written

```
`JavaProfile profile = new JavaProfile(JavaProfile.LaunchMode.COMMAND_LINE);
profile.setLaunchType(JavaProfile.LaunchType.SWING_APPLICATION);
profile.setCommand("Path\\app.exe");
profile.setStartWindowTitle("/Log.*");
WebDriver driver = JavaDesktopDriverProvider.createDriver(profile);

DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("browserName", "java");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platform","any");
        //desiredCapabilities.setCapability();

        RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver = null;
        try {
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`
```